# .NET OneDrive Api Create Folder issue

Tags: c#, .net, directory, onedrive

I'm trying to create a folder withing my Apps/[appName] folder.

Here is the code:

```
var request = OneDriveService.Drive.Special.AppRoot.Request().CreateAsync(new Item()
{
    Name = name,
});

request.Wait();
```

But I keep getting the error message:

> {Code: invalidRequest Throw site: 1c0e.2859 Message: The name in the
>   provided oneDrive.item does not match the name in the URL }

Does anyone know what it means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of **CreateAsync** I write this code:

```
        try
        {
            var documentsBuilder = this.oneDriveClient.Drive.Root.ItemWithPath("Documents");
            var children = await documentsBuilder.Children.Request().GetAsync();
            // try to find existing folder
            var folder = children.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name.Equals("Some folder"));

            // create it if it doesn't exist
            if (folder == null)
            {
                var newFolder = new Item { Name = "Some folder", Folder = new Folder() };
                await documentsBuilder.Children.Request().AddAsync(newFolder);
            }
        }
        catch (OneDriveException exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
```